# Autcomplete - custom renderItem/Menu and item selection issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jQueryUI (1.10.2) and jQuery (1.9.1) with the autocomplete tool.

I have remote json data AND categories AND custom display with an image for each item from the json data (showed in the autocomplete list).

This is my autocomplete init

```
var autoSearch = $("#header-search-text").autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            //I have items with label, value, category and imgPath info
        });
    },
     focus: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log("focus is ");
        //This line shows "null"
        console.log(ui);
        return false;
    },
    minLength: 4,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        //Never shows up
        console.log("selected is ");
        console.log( ui.item);/* ?
        "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
        "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);*/
    },
    open: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
    },
    close: function() {
        $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
    }
}).data('ui-autocomplete');
```

I have a custom _renderMenu

```
//Working
autoSearch._renderMenu = function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,
        currentCategory = "";
        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            console.log(item);
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            that._renderItem( ul, item );
        });
};
```

But when I had the _renderItem, the keys (up and down) for selection doesn't work anymore and I cannot click on anything (no :hover CSS showing up)

```
autoSearch._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    console.log("ul is ");
    console.log(ul);
    return $('<li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="' + base_url + "/"+ item.imgPath + '" alt="" />' + item.label)
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I checked the HTML and I was obviously missing this line in the _renderItem :

```
 //Before the appendTo(ul);
.append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
```

I don't know why nor how but by adding an , jQuery generates a bunch of attributes like

```
id="ui-id-7" class="ui-corner-all" tabindex="-1"
```

Comment: What do you mean, "by adding an ," ?

Comment: I looks like a <a> tag is requirede, otherwise it's not adding the other stufff in menu.refresh